# Xcode 11.3 cannot set target for iOS 13.3, i.e. the option doesn't exist

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, xcode11.3

I upgraded to Xcode 11.3 and Catalina 10.15.2 recently. The release note stated

> Xcode 11.3 includes SDKs for iOS 13.3

<s>However, the iOS 13.3 deployment target, as well as the simulator, doesn't exist.</s>

Edit: 
The iOS 13.3 deployment target doesn't exist.

Is it a bug? Or a problem of my installation? Is there a workaround?

Edit: A Link to the apple developer forum Xcode 11.3: can't select deployment target 13.3 https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/126948

Additional screenshot:
[image: Build settings]
[image: Deployment Info]

Comment: I've checked both the system info>developer, and `$xcodebuild -showsdks`, they show iOS SKDs: and simulators only 13.2. On the other hand, my Xcode, Xcode commandline are exactly the latest, Simulator>device version show iOS 13.3. Is this a common? Or I should reinstall the Xcode?

Comment: I think you're right, it's wrong, it's not your installation. Apple omitted the 13.3 SDK. You can look inside Xcode itself to see this.

Comment: It seems like, as per discussions in the developer forums, the 13.3 support file is still missing, despite the recent xcode update 11.3.1. In case anyone wondering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're right (even though I didn't believe it at first). When you look inside Xcode, the only SDK is iOS 13.2.

[image]

They didn't include the iOS 13.3 SDK even though the release notes claim that they did.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The next Xcode update would probably resolve this issue. I've almost just reinstalled the Xcode if not the macOS.

Comment: I don't think there's any point in reinstalling. Clearly this is what everyone is experiencing. :)

Comment: So now what is the solution dude ios 13.3 is available in xcode 11.3.1 release??

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Catalina download Xcode Beta11.4, it supports 13.3.1

If you are on Mojave you will not be able to install Xcode Beta11.4 but there's still a way.
You can extract the DeviceSupport + SDK files from Beta11.4 copy them in Xcode 11.3
Do not forget the SDK files, without it it didn't work for me.

-M

Comment: Xcode 11.4 is available in App Store. There's no need to install Xcode 11.4 beta.